# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using Laravel Jetstream

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail, laravel-jetstream

I'm learning how to send email to the user whenever their system role change using Laravel 8 and I had this issue where most tutorials that I'm following requires the Google Account to turn on the Less Secure Apps, but I cannot change the settings in the Google Account anymore it says `This setting is no longer available`. I am using Laravel and Jetstream. Below is the error I'm getting:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "myEmail@gmail.com" using the 
following authenticators: "LOGIN", "PLAIN", "XOAUTH2". Authenticator "LOGIN" returned 
"Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and 
Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/? 
p=BadCredentials j2-20020a654282000000b003fe28130b12sm5399227pgp.62 - gsmtp".". Authenticator 
"PLAIN" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 
Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/? 
p=BadCredentials j2-20020a654282000000b003fe28130b12sm5399227pgp.62 - gsmtp".". Authenticator 
"XOAUTH2" returned "Expected response code "235" but got code "334", with message "334 eyJzdGF0dXMiOiI0MDAiLCJzY2hlbWVzIjoiQmVhcmVyIiwic2NvcGUiOiJodHRwczovL21haWwuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8ifQ==".".`
```

Does anyone know how to send emails in laravel or a tutorial on doing it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://www.extendfeature.com/failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-with-username/) to generate new apps password and set your **env** file like this

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_GMAIL@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_GENERATED_PASSWORD 
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

make sure your **port** and **encryption** setting is also changed in
**mail.php**

```
        'smtp' => [
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
        'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
        'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
        'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
        'timeout' => null,
    ],
```

you probably need to clear cache before test it out

```
php artisan config:cache
```